# Problem creating Silverlight Grid columns programmatically on WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, grid

I'm trying to create a user control which will allow me to pass in a list of column definitions and which will create a grid for me.

So far nothing is displaying. Here is the code:

```
List<GridColumn> colList = new List<GridColumn>();
GridColumn col1 = new GridColumn(200, "AAA");
colList.Add(col1);
GridColumn col2 = new GridColumn(200, "BBB");
colList.Add(col2);

BuildColumns(MainGrid, colList)


private void BuildColumns(Grid mainGrid, List<GridColumn> gridColumnList)
{
    // create grid columns
    foreach (GridColumn gridColumn in gridColumnList)
    {
        GridLength len = new GridLength(gridColumn.ColumnWidth);
        ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition {Width = len};
        mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
    }

    // add 2 rows
    GridLength height = new GridLength(100);
    RowDefinition rowDef1 = new RowDefinition {Height = height};
    mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);
    RowDefinition rowDef2 = new RowDefinition {Height = height};
    mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef2);

    // add text blocks to cells
    int colNum = -1;
    foreach (GridColumn gridColumn in gridColumnList)
    {
        colNum++;
        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
        textBlock.Text = gridColumn.ColumnName;
        Grid.SetRow(textBlock, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(textBlock, colNum);
    }
}
```

I have tried increasing the row/column size and refreshing the grid.

This is the same as [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975948/wp7-silverlight-grid-not-showing-content) but the answer did not fix my problem.

This is what it looks like on the phone

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't actually adding the `TextBlock` elements into the visual tree. You need to add them to the `Children` collection on the **mainGrid** `Grid` element supplied to the `BuildColumns` method.

```
private void BuildColumns(Grid mainGrid, List gridColumnList)
{    
    // create grid columns    
    foreach (GridColumn gridColumn in gridColumnList)    
    {        
        GridLength len = new GridLength(gridColumn.ColumnWidth);        
        ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition { Width = len };        
        mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);    
    }    

    // add 2 rows    
    GridLength height = new GridLength(100);    
    RowDefinition rowDef1 = new RowDefinition {Height = height};    
    mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);    
    RowDefinition rowDef2 = new RowDefinition {Height = height};    
    mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef2);    

    // add text blocks to cells    
    int colNum = -1;    
    foreach (GridColumn gridColumn in gridColumnList)    
    {        
        colNum++;        
        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();        
        textBlock.Text = gridColumn.ColumnName;        
        Grid.SetRow(textBlock, 0);        
        Grid.SetColumn(textBlock, colNum);
        mainGrid.Children.Add(textBlock);  // This line makes all the difference.
    }
}
```

Comment: Superb! Works great. Thanks Derek.